# turn off cakephp routing inside a form

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-1.3

```
echo $this->form->create('Cost', array('action' => 'add'));

        echo $this->form->inputs(array(
            'legend' => false,
            'cost_type_id' => array(
                'class' => 'span-8',
                'options' => $cost_types
            )
        ));

        echo $this->html->tag(
            'div',
            $this->form->button(
                sprintf('%s %s',
                    $this->html->image('icons/silk/application_add.png'),
                    __('Create new Cost', true)
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => sprintf('Add')
                )
            ),
            array('class' => 'buttons clearfix')
        );
        echo $this->form->end();
```

I have a routing prefix set, which auto sends this form to

```
/prefix/costs/add
```

Is there a way in which I can turn it off either inside the `form->create`, or `form->button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the route you want to submit the form like this

```
echo $this->Form->create('Cost', array(
    'url' => array('prefix'=>null, 'controller' => 'costs', 'action' => 'add')
));
```

PS: change the url array like any other route array to fit your needs.

Reference: [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create)

Comment: I just tried this and it re-directs to the page, but does not 'post' the data from the form? Is this a separate issue? Any ideas?

Comment: It is a separate issue, but from what I can deduce from your code, you have an add button that's not directly related to $this->Form->end, so you have a js submitting the form?